# Can you set up dbt with CloudSQL?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-sql, dbt

Is it possible to set up dbt so that you build models directly off instances in CloudSQL?

Or do you need to create an external table in BigQuery with a connection to CloudSQL first as a federate query?

I have not seen examples of the former being done so I assume it's not possible because of the storage and application differences but want to confirm with smarter people out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use dbt to build models directly with CloudSQL. Currently dbt has a [verified adapter for Postgres](https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/core/connect-data-platform/postgres-setup) and community adapters for [MySQL](https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/core/connect-data-platform/mysql-setup) and [SQL Server](https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/core/connect-data-platform/mssql-setup).

More info: https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/supported-data-platforms